# Converting String into NSDate in array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, nsdate, nsdictionary

I am doing some requests with an API that returns me the following sample :

```
[{
id = 1004;
"planning_id" = 7;
"started_on" = "2015-05-14";}, 
{
id = 1380;
"planning_id" = 8;
"started_on" = "2015-05-16";}, 
{
id = 1382;
"planning_id" = 8;
"started_on" = "2015-05-18"; }]
```

As you can see, the date value is returned as a string which is considered as AnyObject for now...

I am now trying to change it for all the dictionaries of the array so I can use the started_on value as a NSDate

Here is my code :

```
        for i in 1..<myArray.count
    {

        let dateString = shiftsArray[i-1].objectForKey("started_on") as! String

        //format date
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        var dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

        shiftsArray[i-1].objectForKey("started_on") = dateFromString
    }
```

However, I cannot run the code since I have an error for the last line : "Cannot assign a value of type 'NSDate?' to a value of type "AnyObject?".

The problem is that I don't know how to change the value type of the 'started_on' of the dictionnaries.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Just a tip: When you do 1..<myArray.count and then index-1 you ignore the last element in your array. Unless that is what you want.

Comment: And if your shiftsArray is a let Array or NSArray you cannot change the values inside it. You have to use NSMutableArray or var Array.

Comment: Thank you @Arbitur .
The problem is that later, I use the sort method to sort the array
Or sort cannot be used on mutableArray

Comment: Use Swift Arrays instead of the old boring NS stuff, thats my biggest recommendation to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you set up things before this little snippet in you question but this is how I did:

```
var arr:[[String:AnyObject]] = [["id":1, "planning_id":2, "started_on":"2015-05-13"], ["id":1, "planning_id":2, "started_on":"2015-05-14"], ["id":1, "planning_id":2, "started_on":"2015-05-10"]]

for (i, dict) in enumerate(arr) {
    let dateString = dict["started_on"] as! String

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)

    arr[i]["started_on"] = date
}

// You mentioned that you want to sort it based on date:
arr.sort { obj1, obj2 -> Bool in
    let date1 = obj1["started_on"] as! NSDate
    let date2 = obj2["started_on"] as! NSDate

    return date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Before:

```
var myArray = [
    [
        "id" : 1004,
        "planning_id" : 7,
        "started_on" : "2015-05-14"
    ],
    [
        "id" : 1380,
        "planning_id" : 8,
        "started_on" : "2015-05-16"
    ],
    [
        "id" : 1382,
        "planning_id" : 8,
        "started_on" : "2015-05-18"
    ]
]
```

After:

```
[{
    id = 1004;
    "planning_id" = 7;
    "started_on" = "2015-05-14 07:00:00 +0000";
}, {
    id = 1380;
    "planning_id" = 8;
    "started_on" = "2015-05-16 07:00:00 +0000";
}, {
    id = 1382;
    "planning_id" = 8;
    "started_on" = "2015-05-18 07:00:00 +0000";
}]
```

Comment: Thank you Arbitur.

When I put the code
    `arr[i]["started_on"] = date`

I get this error "Cannot assign a value of type 'NSDate?' to a value of type 'AnyObject?'

Here is how I initiate the Array :

`var shiftsArray: Array<NSDictionary> = []` Then
`shiftsArray = jsonResult.objectForKey("shifts") as! Array`

Comment: Change your type to exactly the type I wrote in my answer

Comment: You can shorten it down too: var shiftsArray = jsonResult["shifts"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]

Comment: Thank you, I now have the same problem as with John Diffool 's answer 

The new object is no longer an array of dictionaries but an array of strings so impossible for me to access any object within this : `[[started_on: 2015-05-13 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1004], [started_on: 2015-06-13 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1035], [started_on: 2015-07-03 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1055], [started_on: 2015-08-25 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1108]`

Comment: As I responded to you in the other answer println prints out a string represenative. The dictionaries does contain NSDates just try access them.

Comment: Actually, when I assign the array, the structure is no longer an array of Dictionaries : `shiftsArray = shiftsList.objectForKey("gardes") as! Array`

Comment: In answer to your suggestion, `println(shiftsArray[0].objectforkey("started_on"))` returns me the error `[String : NSObject] does not have a member named 'objectforkey`

Comment: Thats because Swift Dictionaries doesnt use a function to return a value, it uses subsript: '[ ]' Just like a normal array but you put a key instead of an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it in place then you can use this code:

See my EDIT below.

I would personally want to copy the changes into a new array and you can use map in that case:

```
let newArray = myArray.map { (var obj) -> AnyObject in
    if let dateString = obj["started_on"] as? String {
        //format date
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
        obj["started_on"] = dateFromString
        return obj
    }
    return elem
}
```

**EDIT**

Per your comment, here is an example of changing the date in place:

```
    var myArray: [[String:NSObject]] = [
        [
            "id" : 1004,
            "planning_id" : 7,
            "started_on" : "2015-05-14"
        ],
        [
            "id" : 1380,
            "planning_id" : 8,
            "started_on" : "2015-05-16"
        ],
        [
            "id" : 1382,
            "planning_id" : 8,
            "started_on" : "2015-05-18"
        ]
    ]

for (index, var elem) in myArray.enumerate() {
    if let dateString = elem["started_on"] as? String {
        //format date
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
        elem["started_on"] = dateFromString
        myArray[index] = elem
    }
}
```

Accessing the array after changes:

```
// Returns value in an NSDate 
let nsdate = myArray[0]["started_on"]! // It's an optional!
```

Comment: First option wont change myArray because Arrays and Dictionaries in Swift are structs and not objects.

Comment: Thank you JohnDifool.
Using your method I have the following error

`'[[String : NSObject]]' does not have a member named 'enumerate'`

Comment: Arg. I am on XCode7/Swift2. Try the global function enumerate(myArray) instead and report your findings.

Comment: I just tried it on XCode6 and for (index, var elem) in enumerate(myArray) works for me.

Comment: Thank you, working fine now.
However, the new object is no longer an array of dictionaries but and array of strings so impossible for me to access any object within this : `[[started_on: 2015-05-13 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1004], [started_on: 2015-06-13 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1035], [started_on: 2015-07-03 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1055], [started_on: 2015-08-25 22:00:00 +0000, planning_id: 7, id: 1108],`

Comment: It is an array of Swift Dictionary with the type [String:AnyObject]. What do you want it to be exactly?

Comment: @johnson23 If you assume the array now is an array of strings based on the printl you are incorrect. println used the protocol Printable and everything that uses that protocol has a property returning a String representing that object.

Comment: @Arbitur is right. Println is just a print of the object, not the internal representation. I've added code at the bottom of my original reply to show you how you can access the replaced field.

Comment: Thank you both guys.
This is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with the support. Thanks.